# Recording a phone call in Android

Tags: android

I have seen apps in the Android Marketplace with regards to an app recording an ongoing phone conversation. I am interested in how this is done. Anyone knows how the call is being recorded?

Is there a way to maybe get an Audio Stream for a call in Android?

Cheers!

Comment: Honestly can not believe there's not more activity/interest in the process of recording phone calls on android. Can anyone point to current state of the art and which phones support native call recording. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more searching about and found this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=488475

It states that following phones can be recorded:

- Acer Liquid 100
- Droid Eris
- G1
- General Mobile DSTL1
- HTC Evo
- HTC Dream
- HTC Hero
- HTC Magic
- HTC Tattoo
- MyTouch
- Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 / Mini

I cannot confirm this because I don't own any of the above mentioned phones. Might be worth giving it a go though.

It seems like a combination of hardware support and software versions.

Answer (score 4):

Look at `Permissions.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`: Allows an application to *monitor*, modify, or abort outgoing calls. I don't know about incoming calls though, that may not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that this is available in the API but actually not possible. The only feasible way of doing this is to go on to switch the phone call to speaker mode and record off the microphone. There is no way of internally grabbing the audio in/out stream.