# Android: outgoing call recording without recording ring

Tags: android, recording

I am new in android I want to record a incoming and outgoing call but when I record outgoing call it also record ring. If other side user not answered call then it only record ring it is not feasible , So give me a suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026489/voice-call-recording-application-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502856/recording-a-phone-call-in-android and probably others.